# How to pass an element id and Form value at the same time when using Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying react Ant form design, the following code is work, and by default
seems Ant Form only receive one parameters? which is the Form value?
But now, I want to write a update Form, so I need to pass the item.id at the same time,
any idea, how should I write it?

///////////////////////////////////////This work//////////////////////////////////////

Function:

```
 const createRecord = async (payload) => {
   

    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const result = await axios.post(window.adminAjaxUrl, qs.stringify({
        ...payload,
        // action: 'sv_whiteListEmail_create',
        action: 'sv_whiteListEmail_create',
        _nonce: window.ajaxNonce,
      }));
      
      console.log(result);
     

    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
      handleFormError(form, e.response.data);
    }
  }


  const onFinish = async (values) => {


    const result = await createRecord(values);

    switch (result['status']) {
      case 200:
        message.success(result['message']);
        break;
      case 500:
        message.error(result['message']);
        break;
      case 900:
        message.warning(result['message']);
        break;
      default:
        return ;
    } 

  }
```

Form JSX code:

```
         <Form form={form} onFinish={onFinish} name="control-hooks" layout="vertical">
                <Form.Item
                  name="email"
                  label="Email"

                >
                  <Input placeholder='Please enter Whitelist Email'/>
                </Form.Item>

                <Button
             type='primary'
             htmlType="submit"
            
             style={{margin:'0 0 0 8px'}}
            >
             Submit
            </Button>
            </Form>
```

///////////////////////////////////////Problem//////////////////////////////////////

Here is a list that render all the items in the DB, and every item includes an edit button, how can I pass the item.id and Ant Form value at the same time? by default, seems Ant Form only receive one parameters? which is the Form value?

```
                  <td><Popup
                  trigger={<Button>Edit</Button>}
                  model nested
                  >{
                    close => (
                      <div className='modal'>
                        
                            <Form form={form} onFinish={updateRecord} name="control-hooks" layout="vertical">
                                <Form.Item
                                  name="email"
                                  label="Email"

                                >Current value: {item.email}
                                  <Input placeholder='Please enter Whitelist Email'/>
                                </Form.Item>

                                <Button
                            type='primary'
                            htmlType="submit"
                            //  onClick={createRecord}
                            style={{margin:'0 0 0 8px'}}
                            >
                            Submit
                            </Button>
                            </Form>
                      </div>
                    )
                  }
                    </Popup></td>
```

Here is the updateRecord Function

```
const updateRecord = async () =>{
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const result = await axios.post(window.adminAjaxUrl, qs.stringify({
        id:item.id,
        ...payload,
        // action: 'sv_whiteListEmail_create',
        action: 'sv_whiteListEmail_update',
        _nonce: window.ajaxNonce,
      }));
      
      console.log(result);
      // form.resetFields(); 
      // setLoading(false);
      // return result.data;

    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
      handleFormError(form, e.response.data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that returns another function with the item.id parameter in scope.

For example:

```
const updateRecord = (id) => async (values) => {
  console.log({ id, values });
};

<Form
  form={form}
  onFinish={updateRecord(item.id)}
  name="control-hooks"
  layout="vertical"
>
  ...
</Form>;
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it works fine for you.